# Trying to enable network address translation on iptables

Tags: iptables, ip, vps, port-forwarding

I have an vps which has two interfaces:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:113 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:113 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:11005 (11.0 KB)  TX bytes:11005 (11.0 KB)

venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  P-t-P:127.0.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:714 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:604 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:108787 (108.7 KB)  TX bytes:281389 (281.3 KB)

venet0:0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:87.118.124.244  P-t-P:87.118.124.244  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1

venet0:1  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:87.118.125.244  P-t-P:87.118.125.244  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o vnet0:0 -j MASQUERADE

Warning: weird character in interface `vnet0:0' (No aliases, :, ! or *).
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

I tried to change interface names but I couldn't. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I can see two issues. You've got a typo in saying `vnet0` instead of `venet0`, and you're trying to configure a rule on an IP alias.

This question on [using iptables with IP aliases](https://serverfault.com/questions/167609/iptables-ip-alias-and-port-forwarding) should help you with the second issue.

Comment: Actually, thanks for replying back. I tried venet0:0 still same error. I am trying to setup pptp vpn server on my vps. like in this example http://www.dikant.de/2010/10/08/setting-up-a-vpn-server-on-amazon-ec2/

Comment: My answer pointed out two issues. The second issue is that you can't enable rules on IP aliases (that is, interfaces with `:` in their name). See the link in my answer for ways of achieving the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't use MASQUERADE as it hasn't been virtualized as a module, and that I should use SNAT instead.

This is the command I used, hope it helps someone else!

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 0.0.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source <one of my external IPs>
```