# PAT with IPTABLE over Virtual NIC in a virtual machine

Tags: iptables, vmware-esxi, nat

I have a strange problem and i cannot find a solution. So first, here is my config;
i have got an ESXI with public IP : 1.1.1.1, i host a virtual Ubuntu server with one NIC (configured in my esxi) eth0 with public IP 2.2.2.2, and i have plugged a virutal nic eth0:0 with public IP 3.3.3.3.
Here is my /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 2.2.2.2
        netmask 255.255.255.255
        broadcast 2.2.2.2
        post-up route add 1.1.1.1 dev eth0
        post-up route add default gw 1.1.1.1
        post-down route del 1.1.1.1 dev eth0
        post-down route del default gw 1.1.1.1

auto eth0:0
allow-hotplug eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
        address 3.3.3.3
        netmask 255.255.255.255
        broadcast 3.3.3.3
```

So far so good, its work. I can both ping 2.2.2.2 and 3.3.3.3
Now i want 3.3.3.3:443 to be redirect to 3.3.3.3:8777

So i have made a PAT with iptables like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0:0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination :8777
```

but when i do telnet 3.3.3.3:443 it failed. So i have tried

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 7778 -j DNAT --to-destination :22
```

And telnet 2.2.2.2:443 works fine. So my guess is that it come from the "add route" in my interfaces files but i am not sure.

Any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution had been found here:
[iptables: IP alias and port forwarding](https://serverfault.com/questions/167609/iptables-ip-alias-and-port-forwarding)
So i must not use DNAT like:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0:0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination :8777
```

But REDIRECT :

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d 3.3.3.3 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to 8777
```

That's it!